# How to show Text only post in masonry blog layout and keep the things symmetrical?

Tags: layout, blog

I have designed a masonry layout for blog but what if image is not posted for a blog post. What would be the best way to keep the symmetry intact leading to better pattern, hence UX.

[image]

I thought of adding little logo at the top and then show the text to cover up rest of the height.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot and/or mockup to further illustrate your problem. And also please think about it yourself and add a suggestion on how *you* thought about going about it.

Comment: @msparer I have updated the question with image and my own idea.

Comment: Even if all posts had an image it'd require that the images be exactly the same size, and that all the text is exactly the same length too (and even then you're going to get words and lines wrapping because words are different lengths). Otherwise it's all going be be staggered anyway. And that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend either a block of sample text or a simple placeholder image.

[Pocket](http://getpocket.com/) uses a similar layout that is capable of displaying text snippets, sample images, or thumbnails.  When no suitable image or text is found by their algorithm, a placeholder image is used (see the left-most example in the screenshot below).

[image: pocket example]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like the symmetry in sites. For me, it increases readability. That's just my preference.

Perhaps, instead of images, the 'image boxes' could be filled with medium-sized randomly-floated key works or a extract from the text?

Answer (score 0):

HCD principle. The user does not add an image because its hard for him. Why don't you make it easier for him, such as in, let him choose one of 10 preloaded images as default or upload his own.

Comment: It might be that the user has no interest in adding an image, or that there is nothing suitable for the post.

Comment: that is what **default** was invented for LOL